# How to change the flatfile connection manager “file name” expression values in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am changing an existing SSIS package which has a flat file connection. The connection string property for the connection manager is being set with the following expression:

```
@[User::FilePath]+ @[User::FileName]
```

...where User::FilePath resolves to a path on the C drive. I need to change the value of User::FilePath so that it points to D. Where do I change the value that is pointed to by User::FilePath?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

You've tagged both 2008 and 2012 so the interface is slightly different between the two, but find the Variables window and look at a variable called `FilePath`

It might be as simple as changing it from C:\some\path\here to D:\my\new\path

But the path might have an Expression on it (F4/right click for properties in 2008) and changing the value won't do a thing as the mouse out event will cause the expression to evaluate and you're back at the original value. If it uses an expression, then you need to modify the expression or modify the value in referenced expression. e.g.

```
@[User::FileRoot] + @[User::BasePath]
```

where FileRoot is C: and BasePath is \some\path\here

And that's just your design time value. The value of FilePath could be set through Configuration (external, table, .dtsconfig), run time execution via /SET property etc.

Another place to check is a Foreach File Enumerator. It could be hard coded to point at C:\some\path and it's pulling the directory path into that variable.

Comment: Thanks... I found where to do it. The values of those user variables were stored in the variables window which is accessible by right-clicking on the data flow design service and choosing "variables".. It's really simple I just wasn't familiar with this feature of SSIS.